# Diff'ing only files from one codebase with another simply from the shell?

Tags: bash, find, diff, zsh, xargs

I have two folders that I need to `diff`.  One is a vanilla codebase that has remained untouched.  The other is a codebase that has had some essential files modified undesirably.

I want to take the file list and files of the vanilla codebase and only compare the files of the modified codebase with these in order to get a file by file diff between the two code bases.  In other words, I don't care about extra files, I only want to see what file modifications exist in the modified codebase vs the vanilla.

I tried a few methods with `diff` itself and then using `find` to pass it on into `xargs`, however I couldn't quite get the desired results.  In the end I nearly started writing a script that would parse the file paths from find and then pass the two files to `diff`, however I thought perhaps I should ask here first to see if there is a more "clean" method for approaching this scenario.  Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question. If you don't care about extra files, a simple `diff -ru modified vanilla` should do what you want. If that doesn't help: please explain what exactly you tried, and how the results were different from what you expected.

Comment: So in this case I was able to use your method and then filter out (`grep -v`) the only existent in modified folder to eliminate the ones I did not want.  Seems easier than the method I was considering, however it lacks some granularity i was hoping for.  For example, in this case I am needing to further filter out certain sub paths and feel that perhaps I still may have to rely on writing a script.

Comment: You need to provide more details about the source trees and the desired result of the comparison. As it is your question is to vague for a more accurate answer.